# Angular: Test if EventEmitter subscribtion callback was executed

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have mocked the TranslateService like this:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { LangChangeEvent } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class MockTranslateService {
    onLangChange = new EventEmitter<LangChangeEvent>();
    setDefaultLang(lang: string) { }
    use(lang: string) {
        this.onLangChange.emit({lang: lang} as LangChangeEvent);
     }
}
```

This is the ngOnInit method of my app.component that I'm trying to test:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');

    this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe((langChangeEvent: LangChangeEvent) => {
        this.localStorageService.setItem(LocalStorageService.languageKey, langChangeEvent.lang);
    });
}
```

And this is the test I have written for ngOnInit in app.component.spec.ts to check if ngOnInit saves the language in the local storage:

```
  describe('ngOnInit', () => {
  it('should set new lang key to localStorageService on TranslateService.onLangChange observable emit', () => {
    const localStorageService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(LocalStorageService);
    const translateService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TranslateService);
    spyOn(localStorageService, 'setItem');
    spyOn(translateService.onLangChange, 'emit');
    component.ngOnInit();
    translateService.onLangChange.emit({lang: 'de'}); <----- Shouldn't this have triggered the subscription callback in the ngOnInit of the component?
    expect(translateService.onLangChange.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(localStorageService.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith(LocalStorageService.languageKey, 'de');
});

});
```

This is the output of this test:

[image]

I don't get it. If I call the emit of the EventEmitter in the test, shouldn't that trigger the subscription in the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you create a `spy`:

`spyOn(translateService.onLangChange, 'emit');`

this spy replaces original emit event and the function now works only as spy. You need to change that to:

`spyOn(translateService.onLangChange, 'emit').and.callThrough();`

so that the original `emit` functionality of `EventEmitter` works.

Comment: Isn't it asynchronous only if you set isAsync: true? https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: you are right, didn't know about that :) so i learned something new. I managed to set up my own demo, found the culprit and edited answer.